# How to do logical functions on arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, operation

Is it possible somehow to preform logical functions on arrays like eg.

```
a= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b= [1,3,5,7]
c= a and b

resulting in c=[1,3,5]
```

so only the values that are present in both the arrays.

The same with or eg:

```
d = a OR b 

resulting in b=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

Is this possible somehow in python or are there short functions for this?
Thanks for your response

Comment: look at [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Comment: This is possible when you convert your arrays to numpy arrays. Checkout [Numpy Logic Functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.logic.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists do not support logical operations , but you can do it in sets:

```
a= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b= [1,3,5,7]

c = list(set(a) | set(b))

d = list(set(a) & set(b))

print(c)
# OUTPUT: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print(d)
# OUTPUT: [1, 3, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use python `set` if your collections contain unique values. They are actually mathematical sets: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics) and support general operation for sets such as `intersection` and `union`

```
>>> a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> b = {1, 3, 5, 7}
>>> c = a.intersection(b)
>>> c
{1, 3, 5}
```

Comment: Thank you, this would work as well c=set(a).intersection(set(b)) or d=set(a).union(set(b)) Since I get my arrays from an other function I can convert first. Also a nice way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your snippet:

```
def and_array(a, b):
    return [a[i] for i in range(min(len(a), len(b))) if a[i] in b or b[i] in a]
def or_array(a, b):
    return a + [element for element in b if not element in a]
    
a= [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b= [1,3,5,7]
c = and_array(a, b)
d = or_array(a, b)
print(c)
print(d)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

It is not that fast, avoid this for very large lists and use numpy or build-in functions!